# Load Test method threw exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: load-testing, coded-ui-tests

I created the following Web Coded UI test for my web application.

When executed the test case works successfully.

When the test case is added as part of a "Load test" it starts throwing error messages.

```
Test Error TestError 4 Test method testWithSQLExp.CodedUITest2.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

BTW the same Load test with the same codedUI test work good when the user count is set to 1.

my code is as follows
**UIMap.cs**

```
   public void AssertMethod1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlCell uIItem1363758Cell = this.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindow.UIEConnectFirstMeritBaDocument1.UIMainContent_gvAccounTable.UIItem1363758Cell;
        #endregion
        // Verify that the 'InnerText' property of '$13,637.58' cell equals '$13,637.58'
        Assert.AreEqual(this.AssertMethod1ExpectedValues.UIItem1363758CellInnerText, uIItem1363758Cell.InnerText);
    }

public void RecordedMethod1()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        HtmlEdit uICompanyEdit = this.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindow.UIBusinessDocument.UICompanyEdit;
        HtmlEdit uIUsernameEdit = this.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindow.UIBusinessDocument.UIUsernameEdit;
        HtmlEdit uITxtPasswordEdit = this.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindow.UIEConnectFirstMeritBaDocument.UITxtPasswordEdit;
        #endregion
        // Go to web page 'https://dev.firstmerit.com/business/index.html' using new browser instance
        this.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri(this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIFirstNetHomePageWindWindowUrl));
        // Type 'demo' in 'Company' text box
        uICompanyEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UICompanyEditText;
        // Type '{Tab}' in 'Company' text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uICompanyEdit, this.RecordedMethod1Params.UICompanyEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
        // Type 'user' in 'Username' text box
        uIUsernameEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIUsernameEditText;
        // Type '{Enter}' in 'Username' text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIUsernameEdit, this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIUsernameEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
        // Type '********' in 'txtPassword' text box
        uITxtPasswordEdit.Password = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UITxtPasswordEditPassword;
        // Type '{Enter}' in 'txtPassword' text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uITxtPasswordEdit, this.RecordedMethod1Params.UITxtPasswordEditSendKeys, ModifierKeys.None);
    }
```

**CodedUITest2.cs**

namespace testWithSQLExp
{

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest2
{
    public CodedUITest2()
    {
    }

[TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        // For more information on generated code, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179463
        this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();
        this.UIMap.AssertMethod1();
    }

public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    public UIMap UIMap
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.map == null))
            {
                this.map = new UIMap();
            }

            return this.map;
        }
    }

    private UIMap map;
}
```

}

Comment: The error says `CodedUITestMethod1` threw the exception but that code is not shown. Only one Coded UI test can be run at a time on a computer as Coded UI needs sole access to the mouse, keyboard and screen of the computer. You say that "*the same Load test with the same codedUI test work good when the user count is set to 1*". Running Coded UI tests as part of a load test means providing enough real or virtual machines to support the number of virtual users.

Comment: edited to add the complete file...

Answer (score 0):

found the answer..

[msdn code UI limitation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468125.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468125.aspx)

Coded UI Test Limitations in Load Tests

---

Coded UI Tests drive the mouse and keyboard. Therefore, only 1 virtual user can run coded UI tests per agent. The best way to control this is to set up a separate scenario in the load test, and set the user load to 1 user.

Comment: So my comment on your question had the answer to the problem.